# python display bad docker version

Tags: python, docker, version

I install python 2.7 and docker 19.03. print (docker.version) display a bad version of docker.

```
root@block1:# docker --version
Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d

root@block1:# python
Python 2.7.17 (default, Oct  8 2020, 12:12:24)
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import docker
>>> print(docker.__version__)
1.10.6
>>>
```

I like to force python to display 19.03.13.

Comment: The _program_ docker is distinct from whatever _Python library_ you have

Answer (score 1):

`docker.version` returns the version of the "docker" Python package you installed, which seems to be 1.10.6.

If you want the version of the docker daemon, you could connect to it with the `from_env` method, and then query the version from the client:

```
>>> import docker
>>> docker.version # This is the version of the Python package
'4.4.0'
>>> client = docker.from_env()
>>> client.version()['Version'] # And this is the version of docker
'19.03.13'
```

Comment: Thanks you for the help.    >>> import docker; client = docker.from_env(); client.version()['Version']
u'19.03.13'     . I like to have only 19.03.13